# JavaScript Ajax - Prevent Division by Zero Function

Tags: ajax

I am building a calculator for a class using AJAX. I am having issues with my if else statement not working. It is supposed to display an alert, telling the user that they cannot divide by zero except the alert never shows. I am a beginner to Ajax, if anyone could provide guidance, it'd be greatly appreciated - I know it's probably something simple that I'm overlooking. Below is my function:

...

```
    }

    function divFunc() {

        var fn = "divide";
        getResult(fn);
        event.preventDefault();
        return;

        if (frmMain.txtBxSecNum.value == 0) {
            $('#alert').text("You cannot divide by zero!");
        }  
        else { (frmMain.txtBxFirstNum.value == 0) 
            $('#alert').text("You cannot divide by zero!");

        }
    }
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Please remove 『return;』

This statement does not work because return is added above, so the following statement is not executed

Comment: That’s OK. Have a happy coding : )